# How To Exclude Free Shipping for Specific States In Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

how to off free shipping for specific states.

Example:

I have free shipping for all items over item total $100.

I do not want to have free shipping for USA state of Hawaii, Alaska.

Please advice.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

On select of state create a function in js `onclick=myfunction()`

in that function get your current shipping information from quote and apply

```
if(shipping_state == 'Hawaii')
//refresh whole shipping details
                                var processors = [];
                                rateRegistry.set(quote.shippingAddress().getCacheKey(), null);
                                processors.default =  defaultProcessor;
                                processors['customer-address'] = customerAddressProcessor;
                                var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();
                                if (processors[type]) {
                                    processors[type].getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
                                } else {
                                    processors.default.getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
                                }
}
```

in this if hide that shipping method and refresh the whole shipping details hope you get my point upvote if helps

Comment: can you please help me with file paths where should be executing code –

Comment: just on click of shipping method call a JS function from either same PHTML file or from custom JS file